# Single inverse relationship in Realm models

Tags: ios, swift, lazy-loading, realm

I'm developing a simple iOS app to learn Swift and I'm using Realm.
As far as I know, in Realm inverse relationships are achieved with a `LinkingObjects` property which is a collection containing all objects linked to that one.

Consider this example from the Realm Documentation:

```
class Person: Object {
    // ... other property declarations
    let dogs = List<Dog>()
}

class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
    let owners = LinkingObjects(fromType: Person.self, property: "dogs")
}
```

In my model, I know that each `Dog` instance will only have ***one*** owner since every dog, when created is added to only one `Person`'s `List`.

Now I'd like to have a `owner: Person` property in the `Dog` class that references to its only owner to make the code more intuitive and simpler (instead of having to write `dog.owners.first` every time) while keeping the **lazy-loading** behavior (they are lazily loaded, right?).
I don't know how expensive it is to query the "Linking Objects", but since there will be many "Dogs" around, I think it would be better not to access them on object initialization.

For now these are the solutions I could think of:

1:

```
class Dog: Object {
    let owner: Person = LinkingObjects(fromType: Person.self, property: "dogs").first!
}
```

2a:

```
class Dog: Object {
    private let owners = LinkingObjects(fromType: Person.self, property: "dogs")
    lazy var owner: Person = {return self.owners.first!}()
}
```

2b:

```
class Dog: Object {
    lazy var owner: Person = {
        return LinkingObjects(fromType: Person.self, property: "dogs").first!
    }()
}
```

3:

```
class Dog: Object {

    private let owners = LinkingObjects(fromType: Person.self, property: "dogs")
    var owner: Person {
        return self.owners.first!
    }

}
```

I don't think "solution **1**" is lazy loaded and, as in "solution **2**", the `owner` won't be "auto-updating", however this shouldn't be a problem since in my case a `Dog` won't ever change owner.

What would you recommend to have a **single** inverse relationship in Swift?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way is **3**. Neither **1** nor **2a, 2b** don't work.

Because at present `LinkingObjects`can only be used to initialize a property of type LinkingObjects. Realm reads class definitions and all properties when initializing to define data schema. In the code of **1**, `owner` property is treated as just `Person` property.

**2a** and **2b** also don't work. Because Realm doesn't support `lazy` properties. Also **2b** uses `LinkingObjects` in the wrong way same as **1**.

So, only **3** works as expected.

See also... https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3525#issuecomment-216920757

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set the actual relation on the 'one'-side?

- Specify the connection on the 'one'-side
- Do a query in the getter on the 'many'-side:

So it should read like this:

```
class Dog: Object {

    dynamic var name:String = ""
    dynamic var owner:Owner? = nil

}

class Ownder: Object {

    dynamic var name:String = ""

    var dogs:Results<Dog>? {
        return realm?.objects(Dog).filter(NSPredicate(format: "owner == %@", self))
    }

}
```